# What does Apple Store use for the size of the app for the 150MB download cap

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this has been asked before, but looking for a quick answer.

Does the store use the compressed or uncompressed size for the WIFI cap from the store?

```
App Thinning Size Report for All Variants of testing

Variant: testing-iPhone 6 Plus-etc.ipa
Supported devices: iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPhone X
App + On Demand Resources size: 19.1 MB compressed, 49.3 MB uncompressed
App size: 19.1 MB compressed, 49.3 MB uncompressed
On Demand Resources size: Zero KB compressed, Zero KB uncompressed


Variant: testing-iPod touch (6th generation)-etc.ipa
Supported devices: iPad (5th generation), iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro (10.5-inch), iPad Pro (12.9-inch), iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation), iPad Pro (9.7-inch), iPad mini 2, iPad mini 3, iPad mini 4, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6s, iPhone 7, iPhone 8, iPhone SE, and iPod touch (6th generation)
App + On Demand Resources size: 19 MB compressed, 49.3 MB uncompressed
App size: 19 MB compressed, 49.3 MB uncompressed
On Demand Resources size: Zero KB compressed, Zero KB uncompressed


Variant: testing.ipa
Supported devices: Universal
App + On Demand Resources size: 19.2 MB compressed, 49.4 MB uncompressed
App size: 19.2 MB compressed, 49.4 MB uncompressed
On Demand Resources size: Zero KB compressed, Zero KB uncompressed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main sizes here.

1) The compressed size that can be used to download NOT including the store.  This is the thinning report from XCODE

2) The size the store uses to download, which is NOT the same a 1).  The store adds items to the build that pretty much doubles the compressed size from above.  The app has to be uploaded to iTunes and then the download size can be seen there.

Answer (score 1):

The compressed version is what is downloaded over the air, so that's what is used for the 150 MB download cap.